# Orthogonality relations and orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory

> Let $S$ be a set. We say that $\perp\subseteq S\times S$ is an *orthogonality relation*, if
>
> - $a\perp b\Rightarrow b\perp a$
> - $a\perp a\Rightarrow ((\forall b)(b\perp a))$
> - $((\forall c)(c\perp a\Leftrightarrow c\perp b))\Rightarrow a=b$

Now, it's easy to see that we can define an order on $S$ by $a\le b\Longleftrightarrow(\forall d)(d\perp b\Rightarrow d\perp a)$.

> We say that $(P,\le,',0,1)$ is an *orthocomplementary poset*, if
>
> - $\le$ is an order
> - $(\forall a)(0\le a\le 1)$
> - $a\le b\Rightarrow b'\le a'$
> - $a''=a$
> - $a\wedge a'=0$

Now, the other way around we can define an orthogonality relation on $P$ by $a\perp b\Longleftrightarrow a\le b'$.
The first and the second can be checked easily. But I do not know how to prove the last one. I must miss something easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(P,\leq,',0,1)$ is an orthocomplementary poset where you define $a \perp b$ iff $a \leq b'$, then, if
$$x \perp a \Longleftrightarrow x \perp b,$$
for all $x \in P$, then
$$a \perp a',$$
since $a \leq a'' = a$, whence
$$a' \perp a,$$
by the first condition you claim having proven, yielding
$$a' \perp b,$$
by hypothesis.
Now it follows that $a' \leq b'$, by definition of $\perp$, whence $b \leq a$.
By symmetry, $a \leq b$, and therefore $a=b$.